# Automatic requests leading to 404 errors on a Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, bots

Good afternoon. Almost every day I receive 20-25 requests with an interval of 2 seconds via Apache-HttpClient to the main page of the site, which lead to a 404 error. SEO Frog does not show the presence of 404 errors on the site. Please tell me what this nonsense is and how to get rid of it. The site has wordffence.
Thank you!

I don't know what it is and what to do about it

Comment: This site is for questions about programming